# Remove Loop in Linked List

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I was doing the [Remove loop in Linked List](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/remove-loop-in-linked-list/1#comment-5061596540) challenge on Geeks for Geeks:

> Given a linked list of N nodes such that it may contain a loop.
>
> > A loop here means that the last node of the link list is connected to the node at position X. If the link list does not have any loop, X=0.
>
> Remove the loop from the linked list, if it is present.

I tried with this code:

```
class Solution:
    def removeLoop(self, q):
        slow,prev = q,None
        fast = q
        while slow and fast and fast.next:
            prev = fast
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            if fast == slow:
                print(prev.data)
                prev.next = None
                return
```

But it doesn't work correctly in all the cases.

For example it removes the wrong link when this is the input list:

```
 1 → 2 → 3
     ↑   ↓
     └── 4
```

In that case it removes the link from 2 to 3, while it should remove the link from 4 to 2.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Solution:
    def removeLoop(self, q):
        slow,prev = q,None
        fast = q
        while slow and fast and fast.next:
            prev = fast
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            if fast == slow:
                print(prev.data)  # Outputs 2, but should output 4
                prev.next = None
                return

# Create list 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 
one = Node(1)
two = Node(2)
three = Node(3)
four = Node(4)
one.next = two
two.next = three
three.next = four
# Add a link from last node to second node
four.next = two  # cycle

Solution().removeLoop(one)
```

I don't know where I went wrong?

Comment: use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - and compare it with "calculations" on paper. Use small example data to make it easier. It may help you to see where is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is not correct. It detects the loop correctly -- using Floyd's cycle detection algorithm, but where `slow` and `fast` meet each other is not necessarily the spot where to remove the link.

As a side note: I would not name the given argument `q`... It is common to name the reference to the first node of a list `head`.

We can find the *first* node of the cycle by resetting one of the two references (like `fast`) to the `head`, and then let both references move at equal speeds until they meet *again*. Then you have found the first node that is part of the cycle.

As we really need the *last* node of the cycle (so we can set its `next` attribute to `None`) we need to break that second loop one step earlier:

```py
    def removeLoop(self, head):
        slow = head
        fast = slow
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            if fast == slow:
                # Detected the cycle, but still need to find last node:
                fast = head
                while fast.next != slow.next:
                    fast = fast.next
                    slow = slow.next
                slow.next = None
                return
```

However, if the cycle *includes* the head node, then we are already too late to exit that loop "one step earlier".

One way to solve this, is to prepend a dummy node to the list and make that the temporary head. That way it is sure that this head node is *not* part of the cycle, and we will not be "too late":

```py
    def removeLoop(self, head):
        slow = Node(None)   # A dummy node
        slow.next = head    # Prepend it to the list
        head = fast = slow  # ...and start there
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            if fast == slow:
                fast = head
                while fast.next != slow.next:
                    fast = fast.next
                    slow = slow.next
                slow.next = None
                return
```

Alternatively, you can do it without an extra node by having a `prev` reference following behind `slow` (not `fast` as you had in your code):

```py
    def removeLoop(self, head):
        slow = fast = head
        while fast and fast.next:
            prev = slow  #  maintain a reference to predecessor of slow
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            if fast == slow:
                # Detected the cycle, but still need to find last node:
                fast = head
                while fast != slow:
                    fast = fast.next
                    prev = slow  # ... also here
                    slow = slow.next
                prev.next = None  # and it will be the last node of the cycle
                return
```